# Multi-variate colormap and visualization QGIS

Tags: data-visualization, qgis

I would like to visualize a vector layer by the fraction of three variables on a map. Say I have for each geometry, the fraction of melons (red), apples (green) and oranges (orange).

A geometry with 1.0 melons, 0.0 apples and 0.0 oranges should be red,
a geometry with 0 melons, 0.7 apples and 0.3 oranges should have a color that is a combination of green and orange. Hope you get the idea.

Any tips how to accomplish this in QGIS?

The legend would look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using an Expression to set the fill color of your polygons.

An initial experiment seems like:

```
color_rgb( 
255*("UNEMPLOY" /  maximum(  "UNEMPLOY" )),
255*("SERVICE" /  maximum(  "SERVICE" )),
255*("MANUAL" /  maximum(  "MANUAL" ))
)
```

Will give something like you want but with Red, Green and Blue as the end points. If your data is already scaled to 0-1 then you can avoid the calculations I've had to use.

This generates a pretty ugly map (at least with my data):

[image]

I suspect you could make it prettier either by using HSV color space (`color_hsv`) or by a combination of `create_ramp` and `ramp_color` with some sort of combination of the RGB values.

Finally, the easiest way would probably be a short custom python script that returned a color based on three input values.